# How to output a dictionary to a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I have a dictionary

{'12345': ['paper', '3'], '67890': ['pen', '78'], '11223': ['olive', '100'], '33344': ['book', '18']}

I need to output it to textfile like this:

12345 paper 3

67890 pen 78

11223 olive 100

33344 book 18

i tried this one:

```
output = open("output.txt", "w")
for k, v in dict3.items():
    output.writelines(f'{k} {v}\n')
```

Вut i got this:

12345 ['paper', '3']

67890 ['pen', '78']

11223 ['olive', '100']

33344 ['book', '18']

I have no idea how yo do it.How can I write a dictionary to a text file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace `{v}` with `{v[0]} {v[1]}`:

```
output = open("output.txt", "w")
for k, v in dict3.items():
    output.writelines(f'{k} {v[0]} {v[1]}\n')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help:), I have already tried many ways, but about this one i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

If we want to write a dictionary object, we either need to convert it into string using json or serialize it.
...
Write a dictionary to a file in Python

1. Import Json.
2. Create A Dictionary in-order pass it into text file.
3. Open file in write mode.
4. Use json. dumps() for json string.

For more help and to do it other way around you can approach the following link !!

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-dictionary-to-a-file-in-python/

Comment: Thanks for help, i will try it and read information from the link :)

Comment: Glad to know !!